# Create Google Calendar event from Gmail and add attachment from Email

Tags: gmail, google-calendar, gmail-attachments

Gmail provides the menu entry to create a Google Calendar event from an email conversation. However, this does not automatically attach any attachments found in the email conversation to the calendar event.

Is there any possibility to add attachments of email conversation, from which the calendar entry has been created, to the calendar event?

Comment: I would like to know too. Did you find a solution?